# How can i make my computer use only python3.7?

Tags: python

When i run `python --version` in terminal i get `Python 2.7.18rc1` and all IDEs i use use that. I do have `python3.7` installed so is there a way i can force it to use `python3.7` or something like that?

Comment: What when you run `python3 --version`? Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: yes i am using 20.04

Comment: There is no python2 in 20.04 by default.

Comment: hmm well it is installed and i would like for it to not be how can i delete it?

Comment: `python` always points to python2. That is correct.

Comment: You can remove the `python2` package, but some apps may depend on it.

Comment: ok but how can i do that? sorry im new to linux

Comment: `sudo apt remove python2`. But your IDE, or whatever you installed may require python2.

Comment: "When i run python --version in terminal i get Python 2.7.18rc1" soooooooo don't run it. Run "python3 --version" ;-) "so is there a way i can force it to use python3.7 or something like that?"  your system uses puthon3 by default. I would not mess with this and leave it as is.

Comment: yes but my computer wont use anything but python2 and i need python3.7

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 has Python 3.8 by default. How did you install 3.7? What do you mean by "*my computer wont use anything*"? Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have pyhton2 installed by default.

But some programs may require python2. If you remove it, the programs won't work. Python2 is not compatible with Python3.

You can remove the `python2` package if you are sure you don't need it by running

```
sudo apt remove python2
```

Comment: I made a very small edit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making it *system wide*, you can use [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to maintain multiple Python interpreters of exactly what versions you prefer inside your user account.

That would be my recommendation.